# Python ctypes.string_at , pointer is right, but result string not correct

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am learning how to use ctypes with the following example, but problem strange happens..

The c file is here:

```
typedef struct post {
    char *x;
    char *y;
    int x_z;
} post_t;


void
foo (post_t *o, char *src)
{
    int i=0;

    char *p = src;
    int len = strlen(src);

    for (; *p != '\0'; i++, p++) {
        if (*p == 'x') {
            o->x = p;
            o->x_z = len-i;
        }
    }
    o->y=src;
}
```

And the python codes is here(test.oy):

```
from ctypes import *

foolib = CDLL("./foolib.so")

class Post(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("x", c_void_p),
        ("y", c_void_p),
        ("x_z", c_int),
    )

o = Post()

s = "iooxooiddfggggggggggggvd"

foolib.foo(byref(o), create_string_buffer(s))

print o.x_z

print string_at(o.x, o.x_z)
print string_at(o.y, len(s))
```

The struct `post` is mapping to python `class`. The C file will be a dynamic lib `foolib.so`:

gcc -fPIC -shared -o foolib.so foolib.c

But , the strange thing is , when I run `python test.py`, I got the following output:

```
21
ooiddfggggggggggggvd
ooiddfggggggggggggvd
```

But the `string_at(o.y, len(s))` is excepted to be `iooxooiddfggggggggggggvd` .

Where is wrong with my code? thanks.

By the way, to test it quickly, I put the codes on gist: https://gist.github.com/hit9/7244344

Answer (score 2):

`create_string_buffer(s)` makes a temporary string that is garbage-collected after the function call.  Just pass the actual string since you don't modify it:

```
s = "iooxooiddfggggggggggggvd"
foolib.foo(byref(o), s)
```

Output before change (garbage in second string indicates accessing garbage-collected memory and therefore undefined behavior):

```
21
xooiddfggggggggggggvd
♀ oxooiddfggggggggggggvd
```

Output after change:

```
21
xooiddfggggggggggggvd
iooxooiddfggggggggggggvd
```

Comment: Yes, Python ate the temporary buffer. And thanks for telling me that **I just needn't to create a string buffer**, just pass the original string

Answer (score 0):

Beacause Python GC eat the `create_string_buffer(s)`, yet `src` !

Changed to this will be ok:

```
buf = create_string_buffer(s)
foolib.foo(byref(o), buf)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use c_char_p instead c_void_p.